# How does R2-D2 not remember Yoda or Dagobah

Tags: star-wars

R2-D2 joined Yoda on a trip to Dagobah in the episode "Voices" from season 6.  R2-D2 did not have his memory wiped.  Why did R2 not tell Luke that he's been there before with Yoda?  I know it was a long while after, probably around 22 years, but I feel like I must be missing something...

Comment: R2 has seen and knows a lot of things - Luke and Leia's parentage and Obi-Wan being on Tatooine, for starters. There was once a speculation on Wookiepedia that while R2 wasn't memory wiped, certain things were "locked out", but it wasn't sourced and was edited out.

Comment: Presumably R2 is under the same orders as C-3PO. The canon says that when he saw the lightsaber at Ben's house, he shut down because of a conflict with his programming.